# How do I convert a decimal to a Google.Type.Money in C#

Tags: c#, .net, currency, proto

I have a `decimal` value in my C# program and I want to convert it to the `Google.Type.Money` well-known proto type.  How can I do this without doing the calculations for the units and nanos manually?  Is there an extension method that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `Google.Api.CommonProtos` NuGet package installed, the `Google.Type.Money` type has a `DecimalValue` property that will automatically convert back and forth with the .NET `decimal` type.

create a `Google.Type.Money` from a `decimal`:

```cs
var money = new Google.Type.Money { DecimalValue = 123.45m }
```

Access the `decimal` value of a `Google.Type.Money`:

```cs
var decimalValue = money.DecimalValue;
```

Note that `Google.Type.Money` is implemented with an `int64` for the units and an `int32` to hold the fractional portion ("nanos"), so there are some legal `decimal` values in that can't be represented as a `Google.Type.Money` exactly.  Setting `DecimalValue` will throw in these cases.